# Extracting digits and signs into an array?

Tags: java, string

Consider the string below:

`1.2+3.4*(3.2+2.3)-12.1/3.4*1.8+5.7`

How do I extract each double and each sign into an array,like the one below ?

`a[1]=1.2,a[2]=+,a[3]=3.4,a[4]=*,a[5]=(...`

Comment: You may find [`StreamTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) combined with [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) useful.

Comment: What's the type of your array? You'll need to do define `a` as String[] - is that OK?

Comment: I don't know the length of string, maybe an arraylist

Comment: Do you have to evaluate the expression? what does `(...` mean?

Comment: is `a[5]` just the bracket `(` or is it the bracketed term `(3.2+2.3)`?

Answer (score 1):

With a little help from regex:

```
String s = "1.2+3.4*(3.2+2.3)-12.1/3.4*1.8+5.7";
s.split("(?=[^\\d\\.])|(?<=[^\\d\\.])");
System.out.println("Got: " + Arrays.toString(result));
```

will do the job, let me explain the idea of this regex:
the first part (?=[^\d\.]) will put a split point only if looking ahead i cannot see a digit or '.', lookahead will not move the cursor so if we apply this part alone on the expression we will get:

```
[1.2, +3.4, *, (3.2, +2.3, ), -12.1, /3.4, *1.8, +5.7]
```

now you can see that we need to place a second split point if lookbehind is not a dot or a digit - this is the job of the second part: `(?<=[^\\d\\.])`, if we combine these parts the result that we get would be as expected:

```
[1.2, +, 3.4, *, (, 3.2, +, 2.3, ), -, 12.1, /, 3.4, *, 1.8, +, 5.7]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot though I also want to output the operator

Answer (score 1):

You can examine each character and determine if it's part of a double or an operator.

General idea is:

Loop through String examining one character at a time:

If current character is "(", adds everything inside parentheses to currentDouble.

Else if current character is an operator, adds currentDouble and current operator to ArrayList.

Else, current character must be part of a double, adds character to currentDouble.

```
 public static void main(String[]args){
    String expression = "1.2+3.4*(3.2+2.3)-12.1/3.4*1.8+5.7";
    String currentDouble = "";
    ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();

    for(int i=0; i<expression.length(); i++){
        String current = ""+expression.charAt(i);
        if(current.equals("(")){
            String subExpression = expression.substring(i,expression.indexOf(")",i+1)+1);

            currentDouble+=subExpression;
            i+=subExpression.length()-1;
        }
        else if("+-*/".contains(current)){
            myArray.add(currentDouble);
            currentDouble = "";
            myArray.add(current);
        }
        else{
            currentDouble+=current;
        }
    }

    myArray.add(currentDouble);

    System.out.println(myArray.toString());
    /* USE THIS TO TURN ARRAYLIST INTO STANDARD ARRAY
    Object[] array = myArray.toArray();
    */
}
```

Output:

```
[1.2, +, 3.4, *, (3.2+2.3), -, 12.1, /, 3.4, *, 1.8, +, 5.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it in one line:

```
String[] elements = input.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=\\d)|(?<=[()])|(?=[()])");
```

This works by using (non-consuming) look-arounds to split on any of:

- digit followed by non-digit (except a dot)
- non-digit (except a dot) followed by digit
- after any bracket
- before any bracket

---

Here's some test code:

```
String input = "1.2+3.4*(3.2+2.3)-12.1/3.4*1.8+5.7";
String[] elements = input.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=\\d)|(?<=[()])|(?=[()])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
```

Output:

```
[1.2, +, 3.4, *, (, 3.2, +, 2.3, ), -, 12.1, /, 3.4, *, 1.8, +, 5.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, you should avoid many regular expressions over the same string when possible. Fastest string algorithms are those that perform the minimum number of comparisons on the characters of the input string. Having said that:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExtractNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String text = "1.2+3.4*(3.2+2.3)-12.1/3.4*1.8+5.7";

        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        // Holds a number being parsed. 
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

            char c = text.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.') {
                buff.append(c);
            } else {
                flushBuffer(list, buff);
                list.add(Character.toString(c));
            }
        }

        flushBuffer(list, buff);

        String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        // prints [1.2, +, 3.4, *, (, 3.2, +, 2.3, ), -, 12.1, /, 3.4, *, 1.8, +, 5.7]
    }

    private static void flushBuffer(List<String> list, StringBuilder buff) {
        int l = buff.length();
        if (l > 0) {
            list.add(buff.toString());
            buff.delete(0, l);
        }
    }
}
```

After this code. I still think that you are looking for an expression parser. Which is more complex than this snippet.